# Why could not access Session using asp.net web api?

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-web-api2

In my ASP.NET Web API project, i could access Session object in local (both debug and release model).

But when i deploy it to the server, it doesn't work.

Global.asax

```
public override void Init()
{
    this.PostAuthenticateRequest +=MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest;
    base.Init();
}

void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

UserApiController.cs

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetVerificationCode(string mobileNumber)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mobileNumber) &&
             Regex.Match(mobileNumber, @"^1\d{10}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
        {
            string VerificationCode = "1234";
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["VerificationCode"] = VerificationCode;
            }
            return VerificationCode;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Phone number format is incorrect");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string GetSessionString()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["VerificationCode"].ToString();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" - does it throw an exception ? Generally speaking session state is by default implemented via cookie/HttpCache; common error is that if you have multiple servers on production you need session state provider that will synchronize session state across multiple servers.

Comment: When it was deployed to server ,`HttpContext.Current.Session` always be null.

Comment: Can you check web.config/machine.config on production ? Session state can be turned off via either web.config or machine.config. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks,i didn't change anything yet, and i can use Session now.